Difference In Answer Between Two Valid Solution to a First-Order ODE
I am not sure if this question has been answered before but I was looking to gain some more information as to why you can seemingly have two valid solutions to an ODE with vastly different results. I was attempting the following problem: $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{1}{x^2 - 1}, y(0) = 0$$
Seems pretty straight forward except I didn't know what the integral was and I didn't want to use a lookup table. So I decided to use partial fraction expansion and then take the integral of the decomposed expression. The answer I got was the following: $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{\frac{1}{2}}{x-1} + \frac{\frac{-1}{2}}{x+1}$$
Integrating this gives you: $$y = \frac{1}{2}ln(x-1) - \frac{1}{2}ln(x+1) + C$$
Now I'm sure most people here know that the actual solution to this problem is $-\tanh^{-1}(x)$, but I am curious how this can be? Obviously natural log of $-1$ is undefined so the answer I concluded is wrong, but the math seems valid. If someone could explain where my gap in knowledge is that would be extremely helpful. Also, here is a graph since they are always nice to look at.

Why you say the actual solution is $-\arctan x$? Recall $(\arctan x)'=(x^2+1)^{-1}$.
Moreover, the antiderivative of $(x-1)^{-1}$ is $\ln|x-1|$. You can only determine the sign (positive or negative) only when the initial value is given.
So your actual solution should be $y=\dfrac{1}{2}\ln|x-1|-\dfrac{1}{2}\ln|x+1|+C$ before IV and $y=\dfrac{1}{2}\ln|1-x|-\dfrac{1}{2}\ln(x+1)$, where the domain is defined on $(-1,1)$.

My apologies, I had a typo and it was edited to say arctanh. I got that answer just from a lookup sheet that I saw on the internet. Regardless, thank you for your input. I didn't realize the magnitude of the argument inside the natural log was required to make the defined over the specified domain.
